# Smart Algorithm to identify numbers with wrong sign

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of 1070 numbers (account balances) extracted from a source system, but due to technical issues, some of these values have the wrong sign (so I get for example 100 instead of -100)

I only have one information, once all the values have the correct sign, I will sum up to zero (but of course I have no idea how many figures have a wrong sign).

I tried to brute force a solution with the algorithm below, but it already takes forever when I am just combining 3 numbers (so reversing the sign of 3 numbers out of the 1070).

I believe that even if I optimize the my code, the number of combinations if I for example reverse 565 out of the 1070 elements is so large (5,740547E+319) that any brute force attemps will fail

I am basically trying trying to reverse one value in the list and then check if the sum is 0, then 2 values, 3 values and so on

It of course runs fine with only 6 numbers like below.

Does anybody has a suggestion of to approach that in a smarter way ?

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

test_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,9]) 
index_list = np.arange(0, len(test_list), dtype=np.intp)
sum_list = test_list.sum()

for L in range(1, len(test_list)+1):
    print('current list lenght: ' + str(L))
    for subset in itertools.combinations(index_list, L):
        cur_list = np.array(test_list)        
        check = sum_list - (2 * cur_list[[subset]].sum())
        if check == 0:
            print('found:', subset)
```

This simple example has multiple solutions, the real values are more unique (and positive as well as negative), so I would not worry too much about having multiple solutions.

My list is the following (removed zero values):

```
[511720.02, 39409.62, 14680.43, 731.29, 10387.38, 2256.56, 262681.13, 5897.66, 11060.76, 144271.31, 25914.87, 13015.5, 19316.85, 40208606.69, -5846350.44, -33538929.18, -540682.74, 68089.94, 561696.88, 58050.78, 469706.4, 524.67, 472701.44, 2158456.56, 1158292.03, 100024.37, 18134.69, 337825.89, 10180.76, 2228315.58, 772.53, 8549.91, 43307.27, 39642.75, 72176.45, 323822.22, 962998.36, 135.5, 134388.73, 1473523.1, 275221.49, 34267.25, 549705.04, 247.87, 12958.72, 847714.28, 1781791.26, 3010.0, 1895276.98, 14434.11, 104587.1, 38056.23, 24962.62, 92497.96, 1227702.25, 110346.36, 391.85, 208.41, 8756.85, 782736.47, 3147519.19, 194767.75, 295568.31, 100694.2, 1893.93, 1133698.81, 523.2, 280280.91, 3078.82, 289841.77, 515.2, 175112.67, 24084.99, 35048.85, 49398.15, 41109.64, 1023.53, 782319.87, 28.14, 20.75, 13227.61, 14765.65, 41182.6, 4297.29, 1340.99, 826014.08, 6111.16, 965389.36, 673482.76, 109298.96, 39807.35, 311.79, 437149.28, 1950968.88, 325.21, 2764917.36, 8838.14, 202885.02, 25.49, 999.66, 743027.37, 759.22, 2950.0, 96146.21, 165.2, 21956.69, 1811289.92, 58.0, 6982282.03, 169464.71, 537268.28, 32655.3, 2474912.35, 1066214.61, 87962.0, 81526.67, 49053309.4, 45032405.02, 49548828.59, 48930853.47, 3533339.79, 3343489.4, 61758.14, 52772.61, 1095708.2, 819624.62, 141.17, 8611.75, 88752.23, 14669477.14, 22308370.28, 1215208.59, -183222.0, 99579.07, 621585.75, -26967.75, -787397.0, 18509117.59, 1212170.47, 60214.78, -749.37, 77455.94, 787350.1, 32760.21, 8117.1, 18493.03, 8267483.6, -15627.16, 58625.11, 38622.21, 57.11, 47565.71, 3523.6, 3205.0, 113242.59, 73.76, 782949.24, 5368.09, -4300.0, 2160047.12, -3533.08, 2460435.1, 50990.31, 93463.6, 1487.07, 22470.0, 22470.0, 999344.79, 135237.18, 9281.62, 3430281.72, 7126642.53, -53338.0, 9412.32, 3344946.88, 83075155.43, 17856133.2, 13449.34, 3845.0, 689998.56, 337645.3, 5937356.47, -2491.16, 2199069.77, 167652.42, 3331515.65, 1124710.59, 34075.85, 494639.09, 385540.84, 5891.39, 14378783.44, 7111253.62, 1247695.94, 1.0, 1.0, 138841.22, 0.5, 5979482.63, 1263134.4, 1.0, 5700.4, 12000000.0, 6100000.0, 1850000.0, 1000000.0, 500000.0, 51000.0, 77081.0, 19288853.74, 11600000.0, 4094000.0, 100000.0, 32400.0, 80000.0, 100000.0, 40810000.0, 33500000.0, 2336976.0, 812290.0, 177655.1, 1187432.01, 5224021.89, 4733986.5, 6174765.0, 1646604.82, 535146.3, 695690.19, 2858833.86, 863125.08, 859612.55, 631772.99, 100000.0, -200000.0, -177654.1, 10950.0, 25040.2, 1659670.0, 1143444.46, 3861357.87, 505930.63, 573072.0, 105000.0, 57500.0, -505929.63, -57499.0, 3402777.8, 54270.0, 105000.0, 44717.27, 1725619.5, 928972.0, 382924.78, 110015.09, 500.0, 100000.0, -1779887.33, -105000.0, -44717.27, -1311895.78, 19257544.9, 786109.73, 3885330.13, 9200000.0, 4347805.0, 464486.0, 13300000.0, 500000.0, 900000.0, 4000000.0, 550000.0, 46633144.87, 3657123.02, 2400000.0, 775000.0, 600000.0, 4980000.0, 715092.4, 250000.0, -715092.4, 5407573.99, 6516939.56, 71570143.67, -59186479.4, 1058557.22, -772031.22, 210000.0, 1753591.07, -1630557.07, 37550879.01, 2346460.63, -25169822.77, -1890843.63, 727919.84, -528559.84, 1073986.29, -556999.29, 5547811.48, -3130409.48, 8207549.38, 81942.17, 4489158.99, -7039209.16, -81942.17, -2143400.99, 89544215.17, -37091376.17, 1572011.0, -355928.0, 7478446.23, -595640.23, 32986206.95, -6325980.34, 13565577.0, -2178294.0, 32642339.14, -1005400.0, 3047129.66, 4586021.0, 67050.27, 60878226.61, -2654606.01, -2904000.0, 8393687.95, -18019508.06, -24442013.89, 1215208.59, 177570.85, -18047334.03, -1345725.77, 60214.78, -18212.52, -1823768.35, -354430.28, -8385048.47, 74505.96, -113659.2, 663309.32, -7694.18, -14335.0, 2160047.12, 4953.83, -228189.6, -100945.64, -8846.8, -2000000.0, -1102232.0, 205.2, 700000.0, 1550000.0, 500000.0, -29170503.05, -9741127.06, 2489697.93, -13599529.61, -8942775.78, -32726828.34, -14763682.06, -627846.99, -2340642.03, -4760527.23, -23148108.83, -33891335.24, -24840602.25, -39314900.39, -22877589.68, -2846969.98, -581650.3, -1269764.39, -665159.0, -2846969.98, -418.13, -4545969.04, -2281584.61, -15697827.3, -14778873.52, -18421816.45, -6420171.98, -781896.2, -1038820.41, -80650.97, -142900.19, -614263.27, -15871.81, -3386450.0, 3301075.71, -4058.89, -10407668.35, -8988470.62, -2236.0, -60178.92, -6202.25, -200000.0, -91700.3, -303039.14, -18543.12, -25149.83, -51468.44, -10100.0, -11755.05, -254974.16, -121982.45, -434.1, -853763.93, -100.08, 233961.15, 3521.99, -3776.15, -46650.33, -11412.02, -7970.43, -9798.65, -3942496.09, -1196495.36, -246462.91, -178049.1, -0.01, -18351592.93, -6551763.1, -5598.84, -264535.23, -425063.65, -48942.22, -6434834.64, -684003.27, -7617.96, -543416.91, -596612.84, -2896846.65, -203847.0, 5389.94, -37406548.94, -2609.35, -3543154.17, -83500.0, -1685476.4, -261289.34, -3342018.62, -4850000.0, 1500000.0, 4125000.0, -0.04, -89352.19, -178114.13, -54520.6, -15193100.0, -30960000.0, -3900000.0, -1000000.0, -10000000.0, -8361980.61, -8516941.31, -25000000.0, -5000000.0, -5000000.0, -8170843.24, -472127.77, -25000000.0, -1615441.58, -5697557.72, -18000.0, -810000.0, -362623.0, -526089.98, -8300000.0, -220000.0, 7.62, 15542.39, -25800625.31, -33795061.06, -20780610.38, -4665030.75, -39482892.35, -6840474.74, -18446631.31, -10152810.85, 2216320.89, -83747.0, -403572.0, 21763733.0, -3865209.08, -42267747.62, -263520555.75, 195087.06, -542668069.06, -54499963.22, -46824.57, -80703953.44, -34388289.6, -1120605.64, -1029611.15, -542066.51, -154157.05, -7932466.7, -13257498.78, -11093844.91, -2844716.35, -1361609.65, -5349483.43, -1439399.68, -2694.5, -1181.62, -418050.47, -400674.41, -246043195.73, -44799841.1, -326603330.98, -63937178.0, -37506337.11, -15076181.32, -488966.6, -230800995.11, -10509.4, -7575.0, -106584.18, -36375883.12, -45115231.08, -4305941.08, -9238.75, -516324.15, -10065.15, -2316745.72, -643656.45, -53267.0, -298191.95, -3537748.57, -399554.25, -13437.34, -2112.0, -93177.32, -306454.74, 24222.0, -12000.0, 14364.81, 19851.3, 39903.56, 12000.0, 175747.84, -353732.71, 926.66, -1311895.78, 1365487.35, 623561637.34, 1103900.52, 74.0, 36243106.75, 400408.55, 31379746.27, 1152340.15, 277020.97, 351518.86, 24432.73, 370113.15, 57822.7, 14334602.55, 5085111.06, 141482.62, 2960.2, 17357.8, 933574.99, 116678.06, 7191271.0, 1686605.85, 867515.1, -113006.87, 29156.65, 143305.39, 38947.38, 2992693.68, -504.46, -40954.64, 114478.4, 194370206.88, 24548647.12, 745995.52, 603106175.89, 15577814.31, 38526313.97, 43750465.62, 3.1, 35806829.4, 26656590.6, 1957311.8, 8649.7, 7575.15, 5230.3, 10083.33, 1076.43, 1047611.42, 172125.45, 3686.0, 134997.45, 8605.48, 677961.04, 82822.75, 133569.18, 1961196.0, 91776.21, 245448.12, 821.0, 1341.74, 137930.46, -8990.0, -26766176.74, 424769.32, 142428.86, -18789.13, 268399.38, 50263.7, -85550.06, 125538.91, 6263.29, 19500.75, 245829.52, -1365487.35, 40307915.86, 295222.37, -96036.81, 3166665.78, 1932755.66, 40400.0, -525840.25, 266808.43, 199000.0, -3737.2, 492669.16, -1969978.35, 1708500.83, 2748188.97, 643513.78, 2964400.04, 642333.18, 341338.4, 15289.73, 380235.94, 310.13, 108315.14, 638.16, 11507.44, 48799.64, -382413.8, 406563.18, 11080.63, 129207.66, 32419.8, 465.23, 53502.74, 263531.85, 370042.5, 123341.62, -9786.44, -124800.25, 71673.89, 3318959.25, 597466.94, 182928.82, 28019.14, 319467.85, 1563.75, 1660609.86, -1651940.0, 2806793.29, 84600.0, 27733.67, 714.71, 31198.43, 224970.45, 10020.87, 68734.49, 103156.32, 246821.22, 19097.3, 256539.34, 144102.4, 12122.3, 2604333.41, 191148.48, 94008.23, 6807.85, 2723.89, 5438.84, 122772.35, 156237.16, 24024.39, 705426.92, 187992.86, 132421.04, 241566.49, 102682.38, 41216.24, 4088.52, 1070878.31, 409464.57, 170804.67, 187236.66, 1298978.37, 42352.12, 1483572.01, 2083796.08, 9745.32, 15594.62, 58735.3, 83374.68, 20845.17, 739655.98, 45957.1, 24405.0, 111086.39, 150567.3, 23445.92, 2990.48, 8795.7, 26405.51, 459362.72, 51837.97, 144697.12, 4458.01, 300.0, 29541.52, 1954234.69, 66521.56, 40637.54, 29210.19, 11358.95, 38928.39, 95187.44, 113840.33, 66843.61, 34180.65, 19445.79, 52893.81, 138057.3, 205782.91, 98563.65, 111475.3, 197494.77, 6158.15, 1601.86, 116963.83, -1182305.05, 233113.73, -401948.82, 129.03, 497791.24, 6686.47, 131146.21, 26251.23, 368095.15, 25589.06, 39885.15, 882466.81, 193038.84, 293224.67, 123307.79, -35000.0, 3231.0, -5653952.45, 5469195.26, 243.15, 32610.33, 11495.93, 689585.9, 745.95, 221338.04, 83678.41, 52225.97, 14265.34, 4517.46, 2348.95, 98884.76, 1929.14, 8676.78, 126999.52, 48450.0, 23018.67, 642.63, 11311.66, 86076.58, 59632.21, 1200.0, 244068.03, 738908.91, 1111.06, 53129.02, 18323.65, 254206.26, 16409.53, 22472.94, 49361.21, 796671.0, 2618127.73, 158343.65, 5502.42, -21168.21, -33261.68, -3124673.81, -52827.56, -75.82, -71499.0, -185842.54, 776135.12, -56041.39, -151492.94, 146416.64, -363807.65, -1041536159.36, 1042111293.86, -343423458.56, 343105397.4, -8215190.59, 8189738.0, 10790777.98, 88377.0, 3968265.59, 1089147.0, 177964.0, 203973.0, 249376.0, 1107136.21, -1302612.04, -20665748.07, -268427.98, -1032648.0, -255228.63, -627322.81, -2680023.09, -2759982.21, -1260600.0, 121498.6, 64347.8, 76153.8, -146127.65, -317598.55, -147069.85, 245057.06, -245058.0, -85600.0, -728220.16, -121788.4, 41998.97, -236262.33, 330582.33, 225235.91, -86822.99, 3280734.73, 1734714.87, 14327.0, 6795.0, 49137.0, 334939.46, -375322.2, 2108892.54, 205427.44]
```

Comment: This might help you out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: This is just SUBSET-SUM in a different form. If S is the sum of the absolute values of all the elements, you're looking for a subset that sums to S/2. The numbers in the subset can be given positive sign, the others negative sig. There's never an unique solution as the problem is stated.

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive solution for this - i.e. there could be several solutions within the same set of data. One approach is to look at the current sum total. Let's say it's 200. What you need to do is find any combination of numbers within the dataset whose sum is 200 then invert their signs. Just thoughts for now. I'll try to implement this

Comment: @PaulHankin This particular case of the subset-sum problem, with target sum =S/2, is also called the partition problem.

Comment: Assuming that just a _small_ number of numbers are "wrong", you could at least gain a significant speed-up by using a set instead of a list. E.g. for one wrong number, you just have to check whether the sum itself (or the negative sum) is an element of the set in O(1); for 2 numbers, you do not have to test all combinations of two, but rather for each number check whether the remainder after using that number is in the set, etc. Also, it might help to consider duplicate amounts in the list to reduce the number of combinations.

Comment: The most promising approach would be, to reduce the search space. It's impossible to check all 2^1070 combinations. So I would strongly recomment to reduce the search space by applying some buissenes knowlage. If thease are real Bank accounts, then there are patterns, like montly wages, adn so on...

Comment: Is this your actual real world problem or is it from some coding site and you could link to it so we can read all the information and test solutions ourselves?

Comment: What's the range of the values?

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. In my real dataset. I have 854 values ranging from about -1 billion to +1.1 billion (and some values are very small like 0.01 or 1). I have 216 values that are very close to zero that I can can remove.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of many ways I might try to solve this problem, but the bottom line is you'll never know what side of the equation is supposed to be negative.

+9-6-3 = 0

But this also applies to

-9+6+3 = 0

In other words: Even if you manage to sort out both sides of the equation, you'll always be left with two equally possible outcomes.

Comment: I think OP is aware of this, but even if the algorithm is not able to find the definite culprit, it can still help, e.g. it could then ask the user to double-check some numbers (but not all).

Comment: In practice, 3 incorrect signs is probably much more likely than 1067.

Comment: @Olivier In practice, 1 incorrect value (for example 42 instead of 69) is probably even more likely.

Comment: I fully agree with this, there are probably no more than 5 to 10 % of the values that have the wrong (based on some sample checks), but it is impossible to know which ones (there is unfortunately no logic there...)